# Excel Macro: is it possible to find Row heights and Column widths of a worksheet?

Tags: excel, automation

Is there any way of finding the height of the ROWS from 1 to 50, and the width of the COLUMNS from A to Z in an Excel sheet without manually clicking and writing down the answer?

Thanks

Michael.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To add on top of @Parkyprg

```
Range("A1:A50").Height      ' height of range
Range("A:Z").Width          ' width of range
Range("A1:A50").Rows.Count  ' number or rows in range
Range("A3").Height          ' height of A3 cell
Range("A3").Width           ' width of A3 cell
```

Answer (score 4):

In Excel VBA you can use something like this:

```
Range("A1:A50").Height
```

and

```
Range("A:Z").Width
```

Comment: Would that just give the total height/width? Would it be possible to find out the number of lines in that range? Or possibly the height/width of each Row/Column?

Comment: For one row use Range("A1").Height (or any other number) and for width: Range("A").Width

Answer (score 4):

In Excel vba, getting an output of the row heights is easy to iterate through using the rows.height property:

```
Sub outputRowHeight()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 50
         Debug.Print Rows(i).Address & " is : " & Rows(i).Height
    Next i

End Sub
```

For the column width, we use columns.width property. It is a little trickier because you can't directly iterate through letters of the alphabet, so we need to use the index instead:

```
Sub outputColumnWidths1()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 26 '26th letter is Z
            Debug.Print Columns(i).Address & " is : " & Columns(i).Width
    Next i

End Sub
```

If you want to avoid having to know the index of a letter, you can use an if statement to exit once you're out of range:

```
Sub outputColumnWidths2()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 99 'using 99 as arbitrary high end number
        If Columns(i).Address <> "$AA:$AA" Then
            Debug.Print Columns(i).Address & " is : " & Columns(i).Width
        Else 'once we get outside of A-Z, we want to end.
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

This will produce the same results as the first example, but you can extend it to as many columns you want to by bumping up the iteration number and the first column name of the first one you don't want to evaluate.

Hope this helps!